# "Callback Error: Invalid response from server" from C# ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net application with a button containing the following Javascript to be invoked when it is clicked:-

```
    function calculate() {
        sectionIndex     = getSelectedRadioIndex("section");
        compositionIndex = getSelectedRadioIndex("composition");
        CallBackOU.callback( "calculate"   , sectionIndex, compositionIndex );
    }
```

I can verify that control reaches the last line of this function by setting a breakpoint on it. But instead of invoking the method in the code-behind file...

```
protected void CallBackOU_Callback (object sender, ComponentArt.Web.UI.CallBackEventArgs e)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

I get a dialogue reporting

> Callback Error: Invalid response from server.

This dialogue appears three times, after which the page sits there doing nothing (forever, so far as I can make out).

I can't find any information about this. Can anyone give me any clues or pointers about how to go about diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the signature of the calculate callback method this is only a shot in the dark but some issues i have encounter when invoking web methods from javascript are make sure the method is properly decorated [WebMethod], make sure the method is static, make sure the parameters are of the correct type and named properly (they are infact case sensitive when deserializing JSON iirc). A little more information regarding how the call is made (JSON/XML) and the signature might help. Also, you can try using fiddler to see if you get any more information regarding the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I've now at least got some things to try. I've added the signature of the callback to the question.